# Empty dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

hi i am new in web scraping this code works perfectly but it is printing on the last row into the csv file.I don't know why I printed values also on console and its printing all the rows

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_html('http://www.espn.com/mlb/team/roster/_/name/nyy/new-york-yankees/' ,header= 0)

for df in dfs:
    df.to_csv('losangeles.csv', sep='\t',encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem you overwrite file, always write `df` to same `filename`.

Solution is create unique file names, e.g. add count by `enumerate`:

```
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df.to_csv('losangeles_{}.csv'.format(i), sep='\t',encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: thank you so much. 
what should i do for multiple urls in read_html?

Comment: I think you need loop, `for u in ['url1', 'url2']: dfs = pd.read_html(u)`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't iterate DataFrame. You actually get each row and save it to the same file.

To save all DataFrame in one file, do so:

```
dfs.to_csv('losangeles.csv', sep='\t',encoding='utf-8')
```